# In India, is NASSCOM(NSR) compulsory for an intern?

Tags: internship, india

I am working in a company as an intern, i was about to complete my internship and company is demanding for [NASSCOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NASSCOM) verification. Is it necessary for an intern to complete NASSCOM verification?

Comment: Is it an MNC/Well know company?

Comment: its a small company with 10-15 employees

Answer (score 2):

You're an intern only if you're working in a company.

If the company deems having NASCOM verification mandatory for its employees, as an intern and employee of the organization, you need to get it done.

Answer (score 1):

NASSCOM (NSR) is for background verification. Nowadays, more and more companies are opting for background verification. Its a normal process, although unusual for an internship.

Ask them to give a written offer that internship is confirmed pending background check and then go through background check. Since you should be studying now, the credentials of your current and previous education will be most probably checked.

To summarize, its normal. You cannot just refuse if the company insist. If you have concerns, you can always select another company, as most small companies don't do this.

Comment: I am about to end the internship and they didn't mention the thing in the start. I too not interested in giving them my details. What can I do now?

Comment: This is weird. Background check should have been done before start date. Talk with them and say why they want it now.

Consequences will be they won't give the certificate of internship, most probably.